Why doesn't this function work as intended?
I've been continuing to do my clicker project, and got stuck with a problem.
Basically, I have a dict of 'e'-values (like e0, e3, ...).
When I'm trying to increase the prices in my function, I check if the length of the dict, If it's 1, I multiply it by 1.15, however if theres 2 values, I attempt to convert them into previous value (e-3). If this fails, it multiplies itself.
The code works okay with e0, however when its e3 and higher, it just adds 150 e0 (if e3 is equal to 1), ...
def bigprice(price):
    adv = copy(price)
    adv = {key:adv[key] for key in sorted(adv)}
    print(adv, "sorted")
 
 
    infff = ''
    infff2 = ''
    summofzeros = 0
    for esq in adv:
        if adv[esq] >= 1:
            infff = esq
            break
    for esq2 in adv:
        infff2 = esq2
        break
    for thinges in adv:
        if adv[thinges] == 0:
            summofzeros += 1
    howmany = 0
    if len(adv) == 1:
        if infff == 'e0':
            adv[infff] = round(1.15 * adv[infff])
            return adv
        else:
 
            howmany = adv[infff[0]+str(int(infff[1:]))]
            adv[infff[0] + str(int(infff[1:]))] -= howmany
 
            adv[infff[0] + str(int(infff[1:]) - 3)] += howmany
 
 
 
    if len(adv) == 2:
        if infff == infff2:
 
            howmany = adv[infff2[0] + str(int(infff[1:]) + 3)]
            adv[infff2[0] + str(int(infff2[1:]) + 3)] -= howmany
            adv[infff2] += (howmany * 1000 * 1.30)
            print(infff, infff2, adv, 'good', adv[infff], adv[infff2])
            return adv
        else:
            for i in range(len(price)-1):
                howmany = adv[infff]
                adv[infff] -= howmany
                adv[infff2] += (howmany * 1000 * 1.30)
 
                return adv

Sometimes it converts my values to a float, which is not intended.
I expect it to convert all the values to the lowest, then multiply it by 1.15 (and round it/convert to int) and then convert back.
PS: I have already written the conversion function.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
